# Configure maven-license-plugin to use excludedGroups correctly

Tags: maven, plugins, licensing

When this plugin is attached to the test or package phase, it causes a multi module build to break since it forces dependency resolution before the module dependencies are in the local repository (first build upon updating to a new snapshot version).  I'm trying to get the plugin to ignore the offending com.cons3rt group dependencies which are not required for license output.  Tried several variations of:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>aggregate-add-third-party</id>
                <configuration>
                <excludedGroups>com.cons3rt</excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
        <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate-add-third-party</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

Nothing seems to work - looking at the output of mvn -X, it seems like the plugin is not honoring the configuration setting for excludedGroups.  Anyone have any luck using this configuration approach?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm facing the exact same problem...

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In your configuration use a pipe to separate multiple groupIds and set the `.*` to refer to all sub packages:

```
<excludedGroups>com.group1.*|com.group2.*</excludedGroups>
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this problem is to pass the parameter through the command line using the

-Dlicense.excludedGroups

parameter.

e.g. mvn package -Dlicense.excludedGroups=com.jhla.*

Comment: Setting the property on the command line does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change

```
<excludedGroups>com.cons3rt</excludedGroups>
```

to

```
<excludedGroups>^com\.cons3rt</excludedGroups>
```

as the given string needs to be a regular expression.

For further information, see documentation at:
http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/aggregate-add-third-party-mojo.html